# Redux: Why is store.getState() vs useSelector returning different values?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I have a custom hooks I'm using to fetch values from my redux store and use it in various components.

In the code below you'll see I use `useCustomHook` to return data and loading state from redux. But for some reason that value always seems to lag one render cycle.

For instance, when the button is clicked I expect to see the `dataLoading` in `MyComponent` update right away, but it doesn't. When i check this against `store.getState().loading` I get the correct value. Why is that? Is there some rendering issue with react I'm not picking up here?

```
const useCustomHook = () => {
   const data = useSelector(state => state.data)
   const dataLoading = useSelector(state => state.loading)

   useEffect(() => {
     if (!data && !dataLoading) {
        dispatch(loadMyDataAction());
     }
   }, []);

   const update = (newData) => {
     dispatch(updateData(newData));
   } 

   return {data, dataLoading, update}
}

const MyComponent = () => {
   const {data, dataLoading, update} = useCustomHook(); 
   const store = useStore();

   const continue = () => {
       // Here my data loading doesn't change on click of button. 
       // but value for store.getStore().loading return the right value
      while (dataLoading) {
         console.log("waiting for loading to finish"); 
      }
      window.location = "https://mynewsite.com"
   }

   if (dataLoading) {
     return (<div>Loading</div>); 
   }

   return (
     <div>
      <button onClick={() => update(someRandomData)}>Update</button>
      <button onClick={() => continue()}>Continue</button>
    </div>
  ) 

}
```

**UPDATE:** So after testing the `dataLoading` in a useEffect I can see that the loading value changes in that useEffect. But in my `continue` method it doesn't.

Comment: Your custom hook appears to be missing returning `update`, is that a typo in the question?

Comment: @DrewReese oh yup, it's a typo. I'll fix that.

Comment: also it looks like you're calling `update` on render not on click. do you mean `onClick={() => update(someRandomData)}`

Comment: can you try ```onClick={continue}>``` instead of  ```onClick={() => continue()}``` ?